# Scala keep unique values in list

Tags: list, scala, unique

I want to write a function in Scala that returns the unique values in list.

For example:

```
unique(List("a", "b", "b", "abba", "abba", "abba", "a", "a", "y", "1"))
//> res6: List[String] = List(y, 1)
```

I found a good function in another post but it doesn't do exactly what I want, it also returns the "a", "b" and "abba" and I only want "y" and "1":

```
def keepUnique[A](ls: List[A]) = {
    def loop(set: Set[A], ls: List[A]): List[A] = ls match {
      case hd :: tail if set contains hd => loop(set, tail)
      case hd :: tail                    => hd :: loop(set + hd, tail)
      case Nil                           => Nil
    }

    loop(Set(), ls)
  }
```

Does anyone know how can I tweak this function in order to make it work the way I want?

Comment: You could make a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), and then only keep values with a count of 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

```
scala> List("a", "b", "b", "abba", "abba", "abba", "a", "a", "y", "1")
  .flatten.groupBy(identity).filter(_._2.size == 1).map(_._1)
res5: collection.immutable.Iterable[Char] = List('1', 'y')
```

Your question is kind of unclear though because you don't want unique values from this list

```
List("a", "b", "b", "abba", "abba", "abba", "a", "a", "y", "1")
```

but rather from this one

```
List('a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'y', '1')
```

Comment: Works just great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
scala> List("a", "b", "b", "abba", "abba", "abba", "a", "a", "y", "1")
       .map(_.toString).flatten.toSet
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Char] = Set(a, b, y, 1)
```

EDIT:
So for uniques, I guess you can modify this to:

```
scala> List("a", "b", "b", "abba", "abba", "abba", "a", "a", "y", "1")
       .map(_.toString).flatten.groupBy(identity).filter(_._2.size == 1).map(_._1)
res11: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Char] = List(1, y)
```

Comment: This also returns the "a" and the "b". I only want the unique values like "y" and "1".

Comment: Ah. See what you mean now. @Łukasz beat me to it. That's the correct way then.

Answer (score 0):

A bit simpler:

```
scala> List("a", "b", "b", "abba", "abba", "abba", "a", "a", "y", "1")
  .groupBy(identity).values.filter(_.size ==1).flatten
res3: Iterable[String] = List(y, 1)
```